# How to improve ASP Literal control write performance

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a web application which needs to display the information in a text file in a read only format. I have done this using a string builder and a Literal control (litProgram in the posted code). I read the text file, copy its contents into a new string using string builder, and then set the Literal control's Text property to my new string. Here is the function in the code behind:

```
protected void viewCNC()
{
   // Clear any existing program text
   litProgram.Text = "";
   // Get Workcenter name for folder navigation
   string workcenter = gvDispatchList.SelectedRow.Cells[this.Master.getColumnID("WorkCenter", gvDispatchList)].Text;
   // Get program name from program list
   if (gvPrograms.SelectedRow != null)
   {
     string program = gvPrograms.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;

     // Change label
     lblProgramName.Text = program;

     // Read file
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("\\\\server\\CNCPrograms\\" + workcenter + "\\MasterPrograms\\" + program))
      {
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          while (!sr.EndOfStream)
          {
            sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
            sb.Append("<br/>");
          }

          litProgram.Text = sb.ToString();

          upnlViewCNC.Update();
          modalViewCNC.Show();
       }
   }
   else
   {

       MessageBox msg = new MessageBox();
       msg.Alert("Please select a program.");
    }
}
```

This approach works very well, but the problem arises when I try to display the text from very large files (upwards of 1000 KB). There is a very noticeable lag as the Literal text is updated. I have traced the slowdown to the "litProgram.Text = sb.ToString();" line.

My question is, is this a good approach to use and is there any way for me to make this faster? It is not desirable to have a lag of up to 2-3 seconds while the user waits for the app to finish copying the text to the literal.

Comment: `string myString = sr.ReadToEnd().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");`

Comment: There's a good chance that the slowness is due to transferring nearly 1MB of data back to the client. There will probably also be a lag when the browser is rendering a large html blurb in one shot. One optimization is to cache the content of the text file on the server instead of retrieving it every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StringBuilder.ToString() generates a new string and you have 2 operations a) making a new string and b) assigning it to a literal control

```
litProgram.Text = sb.ToString();
```

To make sure that Literal is slow do

```
string s = sb.ToString();
litProgram.Text = s;
```

and compare it with your previous measures.

Same here

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());
    sb.Append("<br/>");
}
```

According to [this comparison](http://blogs.davelozinski.com/curiousconsultant/csharp-net-fastest-way-to-read-text-files) it might make sense to do as

```
string s = String.Empty;
while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    sb.Append(s);
    sb.Append("<br/>");
}
```

I think, you code looks good and if you have concerns about performance you could check if returning 1M of data in one shot is really required. Return only first 100K and put a scrolling or a "Read More"-button and load rest of file on demand.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I ended up returning the data piece by piece like you mention at the end of your answer. That was its own fun problem, but it works very well now.